# Simple JasperReport generation

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am just working on a simple JasperReport project. So this I have a Java code for authenticating the username and password entered by the user and another Java class file for exporting the report in a .pdf format. So please help me in integrating both the classes and generating the report. I just want to print the username and password in the report.

```
public class Login {
// JDBC driver name and database URL
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/CNVS";

// Database credentials
static final String USER = "root";
static final String PASS = "root";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String userName;
    String password;
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the username");
    userName = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the password");
    password = in.nextLine();

    try {
        // STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        // STEP 3: Open a connection
        // System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        // STEP 4: Execute a query
        // System.out.println("Creating statement...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql;
        sql = "SELECT USER_NAME, PASSWORD FROM USER_INFO WHERE USER_NAME = '" + userName + "'";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        // STEP 5: Extract data from result set

        while (rs.next()) {
            // Retrieve by column name
            String dbUserName = rs.getString("USER_NAME");
            String dbPassword = rs.getString("PASSWORD");

            if (userName.equals(dbUserName) && password.equals(dbPassword)) {
                System.out.println("Successfully Logged in ! ");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter the valid  login credentials");
            }
        }

        // STEP 6: Clean-up environment
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        // Handle errors for JDBC
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle errors for Class.forName
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // finally block used to close resources
        try {
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException se2) {
        }
        try {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}
```

}

And here is the class for Java call

```
public class JavaCallJasperReport { 
public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException,
        ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    String reportSrcFile = "C:/Users/stephenjebaraj_b/Test_Report.jrxml";     
    // First, compile jrxml file.
    JasperReport jasperReport =    JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSrcFile);

    Connection conn = MySQLConnUtils.getMySQLConnection();

    // Parameters for report
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameterMap.put(USER_NAME, dbUserName);
    parameterMap.put(PASSWORD, dbPassword);

    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
            parameters, conn);

    // Make sure the output directory exists.
    File outDir = new File("C:/JasperReport_Test");
    outDir.mkdirs();

    // PDF Exportor.
    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

    ExporterInput exporterInput = new SimpleExporterInput(print);
    // ExporterInput
    exporter.setExporterInput(exporterInput);

    // ExporterOutput
    OutputStreamExporterOutput exporterOutput = new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(
            "C:/JasperReport_Test/TestJasper.pdf");
    // Output
    exporter.setExporterOutput(exporterOutput);

    //
    SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
    exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
    exporter.exportReport();

    System.out.print("Done!");
}
```

}

Comment: You should create the simple report's template (*jrxml* file) and use it. [Sample Reference](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference.html). You can use *Table* component or use the classical design (put fields on *Detail* band)

Comment: eah, I have already created the jrxml file using iReport tool. hence I don't know what should exactly happen in the //parameters for report tag. I'm sorry my question may sound ridiculous cause I'm a beginner and I'm on learning phase. Please help me out Thank you in advance @Alex k .

Comment: I was able to fix the problem but after compiling I'm getting this error. Would you please help me with that .?                     net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter <init> WARNING: The supplied java.sql.Connection object is null. Done!

Answer (score 1):

As @Alex K mentioned, what you have to do is edit jrxml file:

1. Add two report parameter `USER_NAME` and `PASSWORD`. The parameter name must be same as first argument of `parameterMap.put(?, ?)` in `JavaCallJasperReport class`.
2. Edit the report element to display these variables. For example, if you want to display the value of report parameter `PASSWORD` in a **TextField**. Just set it's **Text Field Expression**  to `$P{PASSWORD}`.

For more detail, please refer [this article](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/using-report-parameters).

Comment: Thank you, and I did the same. but in the javacallJasperreport.java class I need to implement the logic to call the USER_NAME and PASSWORD. So can you Please help me with that.?

Comment: I was able to fix the problem but after compiling I'm getting this error. Would you please help me with that .? Mar 11, 2016 7:01:19 PM net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter <init>
WARNING: The supplied java.sql.Connection object is null.
Done!

Comment: Check the `JavaCallJasperReport.java`, Look like the object of `conn=MySQLConnUtils.getMySQLConnection()` is null.

Comment: What do you mean about _implement the logic to call the USER_NAME and PASSWORD_? Do you want to `SELECT USER_NAME, PASSWORD FROM USER_INFO...` and compare the result data with input value? if so, why don't you use the same code in `Login class`...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, however I got the issue fixed but I ended up with a new issue were the pdf is getting generated blank ! could you please help me in fixing it.

Comment: A possible reason is the SQL query return no data. If you use `print when expression` in jrxml, you should also check them. Report item only output when the expression value is `True`.