# Jasper Report with JavaFX

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I create JavaFx project and I need to create invoice design using JasperReports library when I download JasperReports project from SourceForge website the extracted folder don't contain the dist folder which contains the required jar files to build the invoice design the folder contains this folder, what's wrong here "I'm new with JasperReports"

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use a maven [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports)?

Comment: I'm new with jasper, is this maven dependency contain the required jar files?

Comment: Maven will download the jar file and all of its dependencies. So yes, that's all you need.

Comment: ok thanks bro very much, add your answer to let me upvote it, and thanks again

Comment: @M.S. I get this when I link the jar error "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter <init>"

Comment: I user Oracle server with this connection code "connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE",
                                                             "POSData", "root");"

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35934565/simple-jasperreport-generation) out.

Comment: give me "WARNING: The supplied java.sql.Connection object is null."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Maven, JasperReports have a Maven dependency that you can use instead of manually downloading and adding the binaries. You can find the dependency [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports).
The latest version available:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>6.12.2</version>
</dependency>
```